# how can I call a function from an included .as file when the function is defined as a public function in the parent mxml document?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a case where I am using an included .as file in flashbuilder 4.6 (apache flex sdk) (would post code but due to the size of the amount of code I think it would be overkill)... the included file has some AS3 code that runs fine, but I just added a call to a function that's defined in the PARENT mxml document... I get an error that's reporting that the included .as file doesn't know what the function is -- as if it doesn't exist at all.

Is there something I need to append the beginning of the function call?   I know from another project a few days back I discovered during some work on one of my first serious itemrenderer attempts that I had to use outerDocument.  at the front of the function ... i.e -

```
outerDocument.MyFunctionNameHere();
```

as long as my parent document has the function defined as a public function, it should be 'visible' to the code in the included .as file, right?

Comment: Due to basic encapsulation principles; the child document should never directly call methods on the parent.  Does this blog post help you? http://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/1/How-does-one-Flex-Component-talk-to-another-Flex-Component

Comment: @Reboog711 That does make sense now that I step back and think about it... the url was indeed helpful - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helps.

includes.as  - included file

```
// ActionScript file
public function includedFunction(item:Object):String{
    var data = parentFunction(item); //call function from parent mxml
    return data;
}
```

AS3 way (but not bindable)

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[        
    include "includes.as";

    public function parentFunction(data:Object):String{             
        return "Hello From Main MXML";
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:DataGrid dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection(new Array(1,2,3))}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
           <s:GridColumn>
             <s:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                  <s:GridItemRenderer>
                    <s:Label text="{outerDocument['includedFunction'].call(null, new Array(data))}"/>
                  </s:GridItemRenderer>
                </fx:Component>
             </s:itemRenderer>
           </s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>          
     </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

**Proper way**

```
<fx:Script source="includes.as" />
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[   
    public function parentFunction(data:Object):String{             
        return "Hello From Main MXML";
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:DataGrid dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection(new Array(1,2,3))}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
           <s:GridColumn>
             <s:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                  <s:GridItemRenderer>
                    <s:Label text="{outerDocument.includedFunction(data)}"/>
                  </s:GridItemRenderer>
                </fx:Component>
             </s:itemRenderer>
           </s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>          
     </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```